# ECLIPSE E4 - Reading a product's Property

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I'd like to set a variable to be editable on fly thru the Eclipse GUI so I opted for an Extension's Property in org.eclipse.core.runtime.products.

```
<property
               name="myID"
               value="TEST">
         </property>
```

Now I'm getting in trouble since I'm not able to retrive my ID from any class.
With respect to E4 documentation I should use the following method:

```
String getProperty(String key)
```

But so far, the Product variable is not able to get injected, moreover I got ditched in a Discouraged Access while declaring that type of variable.

Where am I wrong? Probably there's a better way to implement this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution:

```
private IProduct product = Platform.getProduct();

    ...

    product.getProperty("myID")
```

Comment: Do you need settings like *Window -> Preferences* in Eclipse?

Comment: Did you refer my previous post about PreferenceDialog? Because in this one I asked something else.

Comment: No, I haven't seen previous post. In this one you asked about some variable, editable through GUI. It can be PreferenceDialog or not.

Comment: It was for a PreferenceDialog, I have a combobox that needs to be updated on runtime.